# Input multiple blob in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to trigger a job when I receive multiple files under the same container/directory in an Azure Storage. Let's say I receive the 2 files:
- mycontainer/uploads/files/file.rtf
- mycontainer/uploads/files/file.txt

The job I want should be triggered when both of those files appear. So I started defining the bindings like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myitem",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myfiles",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputRtf",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "uploads/files/{blobname}.rtf",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputTxt",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "uploads/files/{blobname}.txt",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputRtf",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "output/{blobname}.rtf",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputTxt",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "output/{blobname}.txt",
      "connection": "StorageConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's say for simplicity that the python code just copies the content of the `.txt` file into the `output` container, same for the `.rtf` file. I don't really understand how `queueTrigger` works so I'm pretty sure my config doesn't look right

Answer (score 0):

You will have to confirm that all files needed your function are present and then trigger you function. The input binding won't be able to do it on its own.

You could instead have an [Event Grid Triggered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid) function which is fired for each blob uploaded and for each event you check if the other files required for you actual function are present.

If not, just return ***but*** if all the files are indeed present, trigger your actual function.

You could trigger you actual function with a storage queue message (use the [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue)) that has the filename details required for the blob input bindings.

For examples on using the Queue Trigger binding along with the Blob Input binding, check the [blob input binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#input).

Comment: As you can see in my bindings config, I am trying to use `Queue Trigger` binding along with the `Blob Input` binding, but it is not working. I went on all the docs from Microsoft, but their examples never mention binding to multiple `Blob`. Would you have an example of a configuration that works?

Comment: Well, assuming both the input files are present in blob storage already, you would just have to send a queue message like this - `{"blobname": "<name-of-the-files>"}`. Refer [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads) for JSON payloads in binding expressions.

Comment: oh I see, but as stated in my question `The job I want should be triggered when both of those files appear`

Comment: For that you will need a solution as mentioned in my answer. Basically a second function that is triggered on every new blobs, check if blobs with the same name is present in the other folder and if so, send a queue message which triggers the function you've shared above.

Comment: When you say "check if blobs with the same name is present in the other folder", you mean using `InputBlob` or using some code that fetches the file on the storage? ideally using only the bindings will be best

Comment: Yes. With code checking if the blobs exist. Don't think you can achieve it using just the bindings. If you were using C#, you could have used [Runtime Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-at-runtime). Another option would be to have the client uploading the blobs call a function after upload but I guess that's not what you're looking for.